# Data for atmospheric correction with 6s from Modis

Tags: modis, atmospheric-correction

I want to make an atmospheric correction with [Py6S](https://py6s.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). So, I want to get ozone, water vapor, AOT from Modis - MYD08_D3.

1. I got water vapor from dataset "Atmospheric_Water_Vapor_Mean". The average value is 0.0410000019474 in "cm". Did I take a correct dataset? And how to convert "cm" to "g/cm2"
2. For AOT I took dataset "AOD_550_Dark_Target_Deep_Blue_Combined_Mean" and got average value 0.175000008312 without any unit of measurement. Did I take a correct dataset? Should I covert this value to something?